# Password protected view in Expressjs

Tags: node.js, authentication, express

im trying to set up this scenario:

I have a view /quote/quoteId but for access that view first you need to enter a password (stored in db).

I cant use middlewares because I need to first know quoteId to match with entered password.

What is the best approach to this?

Route code:

```
router.get('/quote/:q', /*passwordAccess,*/ function(req, res) {

   var quoteId = req.params.q || '';

   quotes.findOne({id: quoteId}, function(err, data) {
      if(err){
         console.log(err);
         return next();
      }else if(data === null){
         res.render('404', {msg: "quote not found"});
      }else{
         if(data.isEnabled){
            res.render('quote', {quote: data});
         }else{
            res.render('404', {msg: "quote disabled"});
         }
      }
   });
});
```

I'll need to match a password input of some kind (HTML form I guess) with data.access_password.

Thanks in advance!.

PD: I dont want to use Passwport, because I dont need session and cookies. Just a password match.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,
When you need a password protected page, you should use POST method instead of GET method. Still, if you want to make a GET request like above,

You can send a request like - `<<some server address>>/quote/10?pwd=mypwd`

and you can get your variable in -

`var pwd = req.params.pwd || ''`

Hope this will help you. Thanks

Comment: I need to use get because users should be able to access /quote/3138219321 for example. That solution will probably works, but I need user to enter the password in a form from another view.

Comment: In that case, you can use express-session and put your password in session.

Comment: no...just use express-session to store the password...passport integration is a different case...

Comment: Your example with this code doesen't work, dont know why:

router.get('/test/:q', function(req, res) {

   console.log("id "+req.params.q);
   console.log("pwd "+req.params.pwd);

});
url: /test/someid?pwd=pass